# Unable to understand setState of react js function paramters in a specific call?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

```
      setListOfPosts(curPosts => {            
           let newPosts = [...curPosts];
       newPosts[newPosts.findIndex(p => p.id === postId)].alert = response.data;
        }
  });
```

//is curPosts an instance of array or complete array?? my listofPosts is an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setState call needs to return newPosts, and you're creating an array using the spread operator which is why it's coming back as an array of objects.

I'm not sure what your desired output is, but by adding a return function it will set the state:

```
  setListOfPosts(curPosts => {            
              let newPosts = [...curPosts];
              newPosts[newPosts.findIndex(p => p.id === postId)].alert = response.data;
              return newPosts
            }
      });
```

This is untested but if your logic is correct should return an array of objects with the objects alert value updated.

Another option would be to do your logic before your setState call, by creating a a newState array and then simply updating the state with that new array without the use of the callback.

The callback function is useful if you want to add a new object to state array or do something that preserves the initial state, in your example you could do it without the callback like this:

```
  // Create a copy of the state array that you can manipulate
    const newPosts = [...newPosts]
    
      if (data.response) {
       // Add your logic to the state copy
       newPosts[newPosts.findIndex(p => p.id === postId)].alert = response.data;

       // Replace state with state copy
       setListOfPosts(newPosts)
      }
```

Again untested but hopefully this should help you understand the use of the callback function and the right way to use it.